# How can I use “%” in CSS to change scale of elements?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I’ve tried doing everything but % is not working but everything else is. I don't know why.

```
p{
      width:100%;
     }
```

Comment: `p` are by default block level elements and will take up 100% of their parent's width anyways. This line is redundant.

Comment: It’s not even working with <div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
width: 100%;
```

statement means: 100% of the [width of the parent element](https://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/#article-header-id-3).

To **scale** the element horizontally (e.g. by factor 2.0) use

```
transform: scale(2.0, 1.0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you mean the `font-size` of the element, currently `width: 100%` will not make any changes in `p`, you can also deal with pixels instead of the percentage if you want to see some effect, it would be good also to let you know what you want to do.